# Add "All" variable to an index array formula

Tags: arrays, excel, indexing, match

I am using the below array formula to populate data based on a month selected from a list cell. In this list I also have an "All" option and wanted to write this into the formula so that when "All" is selected the data for the entire year is populated. Is it possible?

**{=IFERROR(INDEX('Governance Reporting Data'!$A$5:$K$999,SMALL(IF($B$3=ReportingMonth,ROW(ReportingMonth)-4,""),ROW(A1)),3),"")}**

I had attempted with the below 'OR' function but when a specific month was selected it wouldn't limit to the specific month's data rather, it would show all data.

**{=IFERROR(INDEX('Governance Reporting Data'!$A$5:$K$999,SMALL(IF(OR($B$3="All",$B$3=ReportingMonth),ROW(ReportingMonth)-4,""),ROW(A1)),3),"")}**

Thanks,

Jesse

Comment: If `All` is selected, will the data output expected be different than if it's just `Month`? If it's `All`, do you expect perhaps `...Row(ReportingYear)`?  All the `Or` one will do is return the `ReportingMonth` row info, when either a `Month` or `All` is selected.  It's certainly possible, but it may help to have some sample/dummy data and expected output.  Do you have a row in there for the year totals?

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your response @BruceWayne ! If 'All' is selected, the data output should be the same just all inclusive. If a 'Month' is selected just the data entered for that reporting month will show (which is currently happening in the first formula, I just haven't incorporated the 'All' option). The Data is drawn from a table with headings ReportingMonth, Date, Provider, Officer, Program, Issue, Description (B4-K4) and then populated into separate worksheet with headings Date, Provider, Officer, Program, Issue, Description. The month or All option is selected from list data in cell B3.